# Oracle - bad date value in DATE column

Tags: oracle

I am faced with strange situation, when Oracle doesn't let me select rows by DATE value, that has in DB.

There is some table with `TRANS_DATE` column (DATE data type).

I am trying to import data from that Oracle to MS Sql Server and import fails with "bad value for DATE column".

After some investigation I found, that there is strange value `'0002-11-30'` in source table.

```
SELECT a
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  trunc(TRANS_DATE) a
FROM OWS.DOC
)
ORDER BY a asc
```

OK, I tried to select rows from Oracle by that value, but I am getting an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM OWS.DOC
WHERE TRANS_DATE='0002-11-30 00:00:00'
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [1847] [22008]: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and  last day of month
```

I already tried this select too:

```
SELECT *
FROM OWS.DOC
WHERE TRANS_DATE=to_date('0002-11-30', 'yyyy-mon-dd')
```

It returns me an error

```
SQL Error [1843] [22008]: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

How should I construct PL-SQL query to select for such data?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM OWS.DOC
WHERE TRANS_DATE=to_date('0002-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM OWS.DOC
WHERE TRANS_DATE=date'0002-11-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'mon' of 'yyyy-mon-dd' is for the character abreviation of the month, try something like this

`select to_date('0002-Nov-30', 'yyyy-mon-dd') from dual`

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> WHERE TRANS_DATE=to_date('0002-11-30', 'yyyy-mon-dd')
> ```
>
> It returns me an error

> ```
> SQL Error [1843] [22008]: ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

---

Look at what you did:

```
to_date('0002-11-30' , 'yyyy-mon-dd')
```

Does `0002-11-30` really looks like `YYYY-MON-DD` to you? Doesn't to me, and - apparently - to Oracle either. `MON` stands for (in English) `JAN`, `FEB`, `MAR`, ... `DEC`. Therefore, match format mask with value:

```
to_date('0002-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your queries I assume that column TRANS_DATE is of datatype DATE. Therefore your queries are incorrect.

> `SELECT * FROM OWS.DOC WHERE TRANS_DATE='0002-11-30 00:00:00';`

In this select you are comparing string datatype against date datatype.

> `SELECT * FROM OWS.DOC WHERE TRANS_DATE=to_date('0002-11-30', 'yyyy-mon-dd');`

In this case you are using "mon" instead of "mm" where "mon" is an textual 3 letter representation of month insted of numeric as your provided. But fixing this would most likely result in no data found as in first query you are truncating dates therefore you must do the same.

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM OWS.DOC WHERE trunc(TRANS_DATE) = to_date('0002-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

SQL Fiddle for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00272/1